# In Python cProfile, what is the difference between calls count and primitive calls count?

Tags: python, profiling

When I display profiling data using `pstats`, the first column is the number of calls for each function.

However, when I sort data, I have choice between `calls`, `ncalls` and `pcalls` keys. Documentation says that `calls` and `ncalls` are *call count*, when `pcalls` is *primitive call count*. Is sorting by `calls` or `ncalls` is the same? What is different with `pcalls`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile

> We define primitive to mean that the call was not induced via recursion.
>
> ...when the function does not recurse, these two values are the same

Sorting by `calls` or `ncalls` is the same.

---

> When there are two numbers in the first column (for example, 43/3), then the latter is the number of primitive calls, and the former is the actual number of calls. Note that when the function does not recurse, these two values are the same, and only the single figure is 
>   printed:

```
In [43]: def a(i):
   ....:     if i == 0:
   ....:         return
   ....:     a(i-1)
   ....:


In [54]: %prun a(0)
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <ipython-input-43-25b7f3d268b8>:1(a)


In [55]: %prun a(1)
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <ipython-input-43-25b7f3d268b8>:1(a)


In [56]: %prun a(3)
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     4/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <ipython-input-43-25b7f3d268b8>:1(a)
```